# JS block button after click and unblock after run code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't solve this problem, my fiddle:

`<https://jsfiddle.net/AlexRoPe/z61unf7m/5/>`

Every time I click the button gets status type "focus", and if I click more than once it executes the searchMatchTablee function multiple times.

I want it to run only once, and when it finishes it can run again.

As can be seen in Fiddle, I used variables to block and methods of blocking, disabled and prop.

```js
window.running = false
window.teste = function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#buttonSearch', function(e) {
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', true)
    searchMatchTablee()
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', false)

  })
}

function searchMatchTablee(callback) {
  if (running) {
    return
  }
  running = true
  console.log('1')
  $('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr').show()
  let wordSearch = $('#form\\:globalFilter').val()
  document.querySelectorAll('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr td:nth-child(1)').forEach((b) => {
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', true)
    console.log('running')
    if (!(b.innerText.includes(wordSearch))) {
      $(b).parent().hide()
    }
  })
  console.log('3')
  running = false
}
teste()
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body"><span id="form:tabelaEspecs">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">
    <div class="wm-flex wm-left wm-custom-button" style="width: 100%"><input id="form:globalFilter" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all wm-borderless-r"> 
      <button id="buttonSearch" type="button" style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;" class="btn btn-success wm-borderless-l wm-button-h">Search</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table  table-bordered table-striped ">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%">Numbers</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr style=""><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>11</td></tr></tbody>
  </table></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please do NOT try to bypass the restrictions SO gives on not pasting a link that can go stale without any code

Comment: Why not `$("#form:globalFilter").on("input",searchMatchTablee)` ?

Comment: Also why this every iteration? `$('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', true)`

Comment: Thank you very much, hope i get help.

Comment: I tried the input now, but it doesn't solve it, the search has to be done only once after I finish typing my number.

Comment: It's called debouncing and you can use setTimeout for that

Comment: prop because:
I tried with jquery (prop and one), js ($ query.disabled = true), callback (to disable after code), with control variables, but nothing seems to work, the code is executed several times before finishing the first, when multiple clicks.

Comment: But i don't know the search time, how can i use settimeout.

Comment: thank you very much, you talked about debouncing, I studied here, understood and managed to solve.

Comment: Great. I tried to simplify an answer but had to reboot

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion

```js
$(function() {
  $('#buttonSearch').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('disabled', true)
    $('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr').show()
    let wordSearch = $('#form\\:globalFilter').val()
    $('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr').each(function() {
      var val = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)").text();
      if (!(val.includes(wordSearch))) {
        $(this).hide()
      }
    })
    $(this).prop('disabled', false)
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body"><span id="form:tabelaEspecs">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">
    <div class="wm-flex wm-left wm-custom-button" style="width: 100%"><input id="form:globalFilter" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all wm-borderless-r"> 
      <button id="buttonSearch" type="button" style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;" class="btn btn-success wm-borderless-l wm-button-h">Search</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table  table-bordered table-striped ">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%">Numbers</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr style=""><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>11</td></tr></tbody>
  </table></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.running = false
window.teste = function() {
  $('body').on('click', '#buttonSearch', function(e) {
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', true)
    searchMatchTablee()
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', false)

  })
}

function searchMatchTablee(callback) {
  if (running) {
    return
  }
  running = true
  console.log('1')
  $('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr').show()
  let wordSearch = $('#form\\:globalFilter').val()
  document.querySelectorAll('.table.table-bordered.table-striped tr td:nth-child(1)').forEach((b) => {
    $('button#buttonSearch').prop('disabled', true)
    console.log('running')
    if (!(b.innerText.includes(wordSearch))) {
      $(b).parent().hide()
    }
  })
  console.log('3')
  running = false
}
teste()
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body"><span id="form:tabelaEspecs">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4 form-group">
    <div class="wm-flex wm-left wm-custom-button" style="width: 100%"><input id="form:globalFilter" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all wm-borderless-r"> 
      <button id="buttonSearch" type="button" style="white-space: nowrap; font-size: 12px;" class="btn btn-success wm-borderless-l wm-button-h">Search</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <table class="table  table-bordered table-striped ">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th style="width: 30%">Numbers</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr style=""><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>9</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>10</td></tr>
    <tr style=""><td>11</td></tr></tbody>
  </table></span>
  </div>
</div>
```